# Prevent repetitive data output in codeigniter sql

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have two tables as shown in the figure below, one table contains the image id, name and the other table contains the tags associated with each image.

**Database tables**

[image: Database tables]

The problem is using the sql query below, I am getting repeated row data, I want to get a single row of data which contains all the tags associated with a particular image id(pid) and so on.

```
$this->db->select('images.pid,images.pname,tag.tags');
$this->db->from('images');
$this->db->join('tag','tag.pid=images.pid'); 
$query=$this->db->get(); 

$res=$query->result_array();

print_r($res);
die() ;
```

output :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [pid] => 102 
        [pname] => IMG2345.JPG 
        [tags] => Travel 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [pid] => 102 
        [pname] => IMG2345.JPG 
        [tags] => Vacation 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [pid] => 103 
        [pname] => IMG1237.JPG 
        [tags] => Mountain 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [pid] => 103 
        [pname] => IMG1237.JPG 
        [tags] => Sunset 
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        [pid] => 103 
        [pname] => IMG1237.JPG 
        [tags] => Nature 
    ) 
    [5] => Array ( 
        [pid] => 104 
        [pname] => IMG7456.JPG 
        [tags] => Beach 
    ) 
    [6] => Array ( 
        [pid] => 104 
        [pname] => IMG7456.JPG 
        [tags] => Sunset 
    ) 
    [7] => Array ( 
        [pid] => 107 
        [pname] => IMG1125.JPG 
        [tags] => Family 
    ) 
    [8] => Array ( 
        [pid] => 107 
        [pname] => IMG1125.JPG 
        [tags] => Travel 
    ) 
    [9] => Array ( 
        [pid] => 107 
        [pname] => IMG1125.JPG 
        [tags] => Beach 
    ) 
)
```

What I want -

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [pid] => 102 
        [pname] => IMG2345.JPG 
        [tags] =>Array(
           [0] => Travel 
           [1] =>Vacation 
        )
    ... 
)
```

Comment: May be you can join the tags as CSV. Try this query 

select images.*, group_concat(tags.TAGS) from images LEFT join tags on images.PID=tags.PID group by images.PID order by images.PID

Answer (score 0):

You may find it a lot easier if you make your model a little more complex (it sounds weird, I know)

try splitting the work the model does like this:

```
$this->db->select('images.pid, images.pname');
$this->db->from('images');

$query = $this->db->get();
$images = $query->result();

foreach ($images as $im)
{
  $this->db->select('tag.tags');
  $this->db->from('tag');
  $this->db->where('tag.pid', $im->pid);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  $tags = $query->result();

  $im->tags = $tags;
}

print_r($images);
```

By doing this, you'll nest the tags on each image exactly how you want them to be

disclaimer: i'm writing this on my cell, there may be a typo somewhere, but this is pretty much what you need

Comment: Thanks very much, this is what I want to achieve.

Comment: Javier's approach will work fine. However, I personally avoid using loops to fetch multiple records. With this approach, you will be querying the DB several times, simply to get the tags for each PID. Instead of this approach, I use JOINS and SQL queries to get the results faster.

Comment: Excellent, used your approach GROUP_CONCAT is perfect and much more efficient. 
Thanks so much Atish Agarwal.